# Error HRESULT 0x88982F72 when trying streaming image file

Tags: c#, wpf, stream, hresult

I'm trying to stream an image file with the simple code below.

```
Stream stream = File.OpenRead(myFileInfo.ToString());
```

When I do it, Visual Studio send me an exception.
This file is a simple jpeg.
In Debug mode, I see with the BitmapDecoder class that my file has not Frames. In comparission with other files of same extension, all have one Frame.

I already try the solution using the FileStream class and it doesn't work :'(

My main code is this :

```
BitmapImage myBitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
using (Stream stream = File.OpenRead(fileInfo.ToString()))
{
    myBitmapImage.BeginInit();
    myBitmapImage.StreamSource = stream;
    myBitmapImage.EndInit();
}
```

It is written in a converter and naturally is binding to a Image control.
But the exception is throw before set in the Image.Source property at the line below :

```
myBitmapImage.EndInit();
```

Another detail : the image file can be open with Photoshop, Paint.net and other programs. When these last save a copy, new files doesn't present problem to open with the same code.

But I can't say to our customers to do this all the time (Approximately 50 times in a day :s).

Thanks.

My excpetion detail below:

```
System.IO.IOException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146232800
  Message=Impossible de lire à partir du flux.
  Source=PresentationCore
  StackTrace:
       à System.Windows.Media.ColorContext.GetColorContextsHelper(GetColorContextsDelegate getColorContexts)
       à System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapFrameDecode.get_ColorContexts()
       à System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage.FinalizeCreation()
       à System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage.EndInit()
       à EDIs.Imaging.Converter.UriToBitmapSourceConverter.Convert(Object value, Type targetType, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture) dans C:\Users\Gaet\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\DotNet\MDP.EDIs\EDIs.Imaging\Converter\UriToBitmapSourceConverter.cs:ligne 40
       à System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.TransferValue(Object newValue, Boolean isASubPropertyChange)
       à System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.Activate(Object item)
       à System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.AttachToContext(AttachAttempt attempt)
       à System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.AttachOverride(DependencyObject target, DependencyProperty dp)
       à System.Windows.Data.BindingExpressionBase.OnAttach(DependencyObject d, DependencyProperty dp)
       à System.Windows.StyleHelper.GetInstanceValue(UncommonField`1 dataField, DependencyObject container, FrameworkElement feChild, FrameworkContentElement fceChild, Int32 childIndex, DependencyProperty dp, Int32 i, EffectiveValueEntry& entry)
       à System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.ReceivePropertySet(Object targetObject, XamlMember member, Object value, DependencyObject templatedParent)
       à System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.<>c__DisplayClass6.<LoadOptimizedTemplateContent>b__4(Object sender, XamlSetValueEventArgs setArgs)
       à System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.OnSetValue(Object eventSender, XamlMember member, Object value)
       à System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.Logic_ApplyPropertyValue(ObjectWriterContext ctx, XamlMember prop, Object value, Boolean onParent)
       à System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.Logic_DoAssignmentToParentProperty(ObjectWriterContext ctx)
       à System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.Logic_AssignProvidedValue(ObjectWriterContext ctx)
       à System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.WriteEndObject()
       à System.Xaml.XamlWriter.WriteNode(XamlReader reader)
       à System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.LoadTemplateXaml(XamlReader templateReader, XamlObjectWriter currentWriter)
  InnerException: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
       HResult=-2003292302
       Message=Exception de HRESULT : 0x88982F72
       ErrorCode=-2003292302
       InnerException:
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this blog post by Scott Hanselman [Dealing with Images with Bad Metadata - Corrupted Color Profiles in WPF](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/DealingWithImagesWithBadMetadataCorruptedColorProfilesInWPF.aspx)

His suggested fix worked in my case. From the blog:

```
var bi = new BitmapImage();
bi.BeginInit();
    bi.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreColorProfile;
    bi.UriSource = new Uri("http://hanselman.com/blog/images/JPGwithBadColorProfile.jpg");
bi.EndInit();

foo.Source = bi;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
    BitmapImage Art3 = new BitmapImage();
    using (FileStream stream = File.OpenRead("c:\\temp\\Album.jpg"))
    {
        Art3.BeginInit();
        Art3.StreamSource = stream;
        Art3.EndInit();
    }
    artwork.Source = Art3;
```

"artwork" is the XAML object where image is supposed to be shown.